# why git merge remove existing line of code

Tags: git

I have a problem which is I don't know about it
so I have two branch:

- main
- feature

and i have one file for every branches say **demo_file** which contain some text:

**main branch:**

- one
- two
- three
- four

Then i create new branch **git checkout -b feature**

 **feature branch:**

- one
- two
- three

so I have removed last line(- four)
after that I have to switched to main branch and doing merge with feature branch
but why existing line in main branch is removed?

expected:
So I wanna get a conflict message for this merge, not auto remove line but how?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Merging means you want to have changes from feature included in master. So it includes them and deletes the line.

A merge conflict would happen if you did another change in master. Say in feature you delete it, in master you change it. That is a conflict that needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

> So I wanna get a conflict message for this merge

You cannot get a conflict message because there is no conflict.

If you want to inspect the effect of the merge commit before completely performing the merge, then when you give your merge command, attach the `--no-commit` flag to it. Git responds by configuring your working tree and your index as if it were about to make the merge commit, but it doesn’t actually make the commit. Instead, Git pauses in the middle of the merge operation so that you can inspect the merged files in the working tree.

Since no commit was actually performed, you can now compare the “merged” state of the working tree with its previous state by saying `git diff HEAD`. You can modify what the merge does, and then say `git commit`. Note, however, you are now creating what is arguably an "evil merge" (i.e. you're calling it a merge but the commit is not the actual result of merging).